# Project Euler #45: How is my logic wrong?

Tags: python

From Project Euler, problem 45:

> ```
> Triangle, pentagonal, and hexagonal numbers are generated by the following formulae:
>
> Triangle T_(n)=n(n+1)/2 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...
>
> Pentagonal P_(n)=n(3n−1)/2 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, ...
>
> Hexagonal H_(n)=n(2n−1) 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, ...
>
> It can be verified that T_(285) = P_(165) = H_(143) = 40755.
>
> Find the next triangle number that is also pentagonal and hexagonal.
> ```

[ http://projecteuler.net/problem=45 ]

Now to solve them I took three variables and equated the equations to A.

```
n(n + 1)/2 = a(3a - 1)/2 = b(2b - 1) = A
```

A = number at which the threee function coincide for values of n, a, b

Resultant we get 3 equations with n and A. Solving with quarditic formula, we get 3 equations.

```
 (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8*A ) )/2
 ( 1 + sqrt(1 + 24*A) )/6
 ( 1 + sqrt(1 + 8*A ) )/4
```

So my logic is to test for values of A at which the three equation give a natural +ve value. So far it works correct for number **40755** but fails to find the next one upto 10 million.

**(Edit):** Here is my code in python

```
from math import *

i=10000000
while(1):
    i = i + 1
    if(((-1+sqrt(1+8*i))/2).is_integer()):
        if(((1+sqrt(1+24*i))/6).is_integer()):
            if(((1+sqrt(1+8*i))/4).is_integer()):
                print i
                break
```

How is my logic wrong? (*Apologies for a bit of maths involved. :)* )

Comment: (slight optimization): All hexagonal numbers are also triangular.

Comment: You also seem to test all integers. You could speed up by first calculating the hexagonals and then test them (if they are pentagonals, too).

Comment: Um, is that really how is_integer works? Your number is still going to come as a double type after the calculations, regardless of whether the number is close to an integer, so won't it always return false?

Maybe you should write your own integer-check function so you know what it is doing.

Comment: Oh I've looked up the function and yes it does what you want it to, but I'd be a bit concerned about rounding errors, so it can't hurt to write your own test for integers instead. When I solved this problem I rounded the square-rooted number down, then re-applied the triangle formula to see if I got back to the triangle number.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for your thought. Never thought of optimization. Always thought it was logical flaw :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is not wrong, your program just takes a long time to run (by my estimate it should provide an answer in about an hour). I know the answer and tested your program by setting `i` to a value just below it. Your program then popped out the right answer at once.

Heed the advice of ypercube.

Answer (score 3):

Given that:

- all hexagonals are also triangulars
- `heapq.merge` is quite handy for the task at hand (efficient and saves code)

then this:

```
import heapq

def hexagonals():
    "Simplified generation of hexagonals"
    n= 1
    dn= 5
    while 1:
        yield n
        n+= dn
        dn+= 4

def pentagonals():
    n= 1
    dn= 4
    while 1:
        yield n
        n+= dn
        dn+= 3

def main():
    last_n= 0
    for n in heapq.merge(hexagonals(), pentagonals()):
        if n == last_n:
            print n
        last_n= n

main()
```

produces 1, 40755 and the other number you're seeking in almost no time, and a few seconds later a 14-digit number. Just stop the program when you think you burned enough electricity.

In case you want to avoid “opaque” libraries, use the following `main` (essentially the same algorithm, only spelled out):

```
def main():
    hexagonal= hexagonals()
    pentagonal= pentagonals()
    h= next(hexagonal)
    p= next(pentagonal)
    while 1:
        while p < h:
            p= next(pentagonal)
        if p == h:
            print p
        h= next(hexagonal)
```

Times look similar, but I didn't bother to benchmark.

Comment: One could also use `next_hexagonal= hexagonals().next; h= next_hexagonal()` etc, but at some point in time one should drop micro-optimizing and go straight to bed, and that time is now :)

Comment: +1 This is awesome! heapq only generates a few elements at the time, god to know.

Comment: To the downvoter: please give a reason for the downvoting; if the answer is not useful, help me make it useful. “I don't like this” or “I don't like you” is not a basis for downvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to implement is to make 3 generators for each sequence and route them in

`heapq.merge`

and then if you find 3 same consecitive keys you got solution 
Simplest way to find this is usnig

`itertools.groupby`

Comment: I think that way of thinking about a problem is probably quite foreign to the OP...